# Finding item row index in ListView by text and by column

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the following code to retrieve the index of a row that contains certain text in the second column (of which it has 3, an index one, and two that contain other text).

```
LVFINDINFO inf={0};
inf.flags=LVFI_PARCIAL|LVFI_STRING;
inf.psz="textToFind";
std::cout<<ListView_FindItem(mywinHandle, -1, (LPARAM)&inf);
```

However, this will only return -1 as it will search in the first column (the index one -- on 15 input, will return 15, etc.). I've tried understanding the way to use the lParam member to search in other specific column (if that's even possible), but couldn't even when I added as a lParam a LVITEM with the correct Item member. I just couldn't quite find the way here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any reason you can't just write a for loop. and go through each item one by one until you find the one you are looking for?

Comment: @jahhaj you mean getting item by item by index -- that might actually work. But I'm wondering if there is any way around this. Thanks for the answer though, if I'm not able to find a way to do it I'll just make a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't search in the sub-columns. You can only search in the primary column.

The `lParam` value specifies which row to start searching from. You are mistaken in thinking that it allows you to specify which column to search.

Comment: I see. I'll have to rely on using a loop or another method. Thanks!